# Getting superscripts in math mode without the ^ character

Tags: math-mode, superscripts, mathjax

Is there a way to get the superscript math mode behavior without using `^`?

By way of background: I work at a large school that has a large web site that occasionally has math content on pages. I recently convinced the powers that be to start using MathJax to render all of the math content, but they have encountered a hitch. There is a collection of pages that is processed by complicated subsystems in an automated way, and I'm told that the `^` character is a control character at some stage(s).

So either they have to work around that, or I could start communicating the math without using `^` symbol. (I understand that I may still have a MathJax issue to move on to, but my issue starts with this LaTeX question.)

Comment: Is this a LaTeX question? MathJax questions are off-topic

Comment: In (La)TeX it's possible to use `\sp` instead of `^` for exponents; it doesn't seem possible in MathJax. Nothing can be done other than making a feature request to the developers. However, I have tried `$\def\sp{^}a\sp{b}$` on a page where MathJax is used and it appears to work, so it may be possible to add `\def\sp{^}` to some initialization file.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But mathjax is a recognized tag at this site, as you can see. So is that really true? In any case, it is not necessarily a MathJax question. If there exists a LaTeX command like, say, `\mathsuperscript{}`, then that would answer my question here. I'd move on to see if MathJAx supports it.

Comment: @alex.jordan: MathJax uses the same syntax (or supports at least some commands) as (La)TeX, but the engine behind it is different.

Comment: you could do `\newcommand\sp[1]{^{#1}}` to define \sp in mathjax (or use another name, as the behaviour is slightly different.

Comment: `^` as a control character…I feel a little hypocritical for saying this, but that's abhorrent.

Comment: If your page is pre-processed before being sent to the browser, you might be able to use `&#x5E;` in place of the `^` (either in your math expressions, or in the definition of `\sp`) in order to get past the pre-processing of `^`.  This is will be converted to the circumflex by the browser, but is not a literal `^` in the source file.

Comment: I tried \sp and \sb in place of ^ and _ in a LaTex \documentclass{article} file and they worked. But in MathJax via StackExchange Physics, it won't typeset e.g. `$a = x\sp2$` or `$y = cx\sb6$`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

in `latex.ltx` there is a line

```
\let\sp=^
```

so there is an alternate command, `\sp`, that will produce a superscript.

@egreg notes in a comment that this isn't available for mathjax, so it's
apparently not "portable".  however, david cervone (mathjax lead developer) says that

> MathJax does handle `\let\sp=^` [...]. MathJax's `\let` only works to
>   set a control sequence name, not another character, so you can't do
>   `\let!=^`, for example, but setting `\sp` would certainly work.

this command is inherited from `plain.tex`.  in the *texbook* (p.135)

> `\danger` If for some reason you cannot use `^` and `_` for superscripts
>   and subscripts, because you have an unusual keyboard or because you
>   need `^` for French accents or something, plain TeX lets you type
>   `\sp` and `\sb` instead. For example, `$x\sp2$` is another way to
>   get *x*<sup>2</sup>. On the other hand, some people are lucky enough to have
>   keyboards that contain additional symbols besides those of standard
>   ASCII.

Comment: Why is the macro named `\sp`? `\stackpowers`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\let\sb=_` is the analog: SuPerscript and SuBscript.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- shorthand defined by knuth.  this line in `plain.tex': `\let\sp=^ \let\sb=_`.  adding note to answer.

Comment: Can you add the original `|verb|` to the quote? I was a bit confused reading *`$x\sp2$` is another way to get `$x\sp2$`*. Or simply leaving out the code-markup for the second instance might do just as fine.

Comment: Perhaps extend the answer to mention that any token could be `\let` to `^`, or indeed the `\catcode` could be set to 7, to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, MathJax does handle `\let\sp=^`, so I'm not sure where that claim is coming from.  MathJax's `\let` only works to set a control sequence name, not another character, so you can't do `\let!=^`, for example, but setting `\sp` would certainly work.  Perhaps that is the source of the claim.

Comment: @DavideCervone: I never denied that. I just stated that the background engine is different

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, sorry, I tagged the wrong user, and didn't notice until after I could no longer edit the comment.  It was apparently egreg who made the comment (as noted in Barbara's answer above, though I don't see egreg's original note to that effect).  My apologies.

Comment: @DavideCervone: No worries. Such 'errors' happen ;-)

Comment: @DavideCervone -- egreg's comment (that `\sb` doesn't *natively* work with mathjax) was the second one posted to the question, not to this answer.  (i'm happy to crib useful information from anywhere, provided i have a reasonable feeling that it's accurate.  so thanks to you for clarifying that a simple `\let` will provide the feature.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thanks for pointing out where the comment came from.  I misread the citation to mean that egreg said that *your* approach with `\let` wasn't portable.  Clearly I wasn't paying enough attention that day!