# Is \sp a reserved word in TikZ math library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I was running a \tikzmath function as shown below:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {math}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   % required for coordinate calculations
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \draw[loosely dashed] (0,0) grid [step=2] (5,5)
\tikzmath{
    function    arcStartPoint(\cx, \cy, \bAngle, \eAngle, \radius)  {
        coordinate \sp; % arc starting point
        \sp = (\cx, \cy) + ({\radius * cos(\bAngle)}, {\radius * sin(\bAngle)});
        { \draw[ultra thick, orange] (\sp) arc (\bAngle:\eAngle:\radius);   };
    };
    arcStartPoint(1, 2, -30, 30, 1);
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and got lots of errors:

> l.8 \tikzmath
> ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
>
> \sp
> l.15 }
> ;
> The control sequence marked  should
> not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

> ! Extra \endcsname.
> \tikz@math@next ...ocess@keyword@ \sp =\endcsname

Once I changed \sp to \spt, it worked. Is \sp a reserved word?

Comment: what do you mean by reserved word? it's a standard latex command for superscript, like `^`

Comment: It has this error `\tikz@math@next ...ocess@keyword@ \sp`

Comment: I don't know anything about tikzmath functions but I guess that the coordinate is fed to a `\csname`. The control sequence `\sp` is an implicit character token and cannot appear between `\csname` and `\endcsname`.

Comment: Somewhat reverse question: [Getting superscripts in math mode without the ^ character - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246293/getting-superscripts-in-math-mode-without-the-character)